# uiautomator for android, path problem

Tags: android, testing-environment

i'm a newbie on linux, android and QA at the same time.

following this tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html#sample
I came across to this situation:

```
filip@TowardMac:~/workspace_adt/TestSample$ ant build
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar 
Buildfile: /home/filip/workspace_adt/TestSample/build.xml

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.3.0
 [checkenv] Installed at /home/filip/Development/adt-bundle/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.0
 [echo] Resolving Build Target for TestSample...
[getuitarget] Project Target:   Android 4.1.2
[getuitarget] API level:        16
 [echo] ----------
 [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
[mkdir] Created dir: /home/filip/workspace_adt/TestSample/bin/classes

-pre-compile:

compile:

BUILD FAILED
/home/filip/Development/adt-bundle/adt-bundle-linux-x86_6420131030/sdk/tools/ant/uibuild.xml:183: 
Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre"

Total time: 1 second
filip@TowardMac:~/workspace_adt/TestSample$
```

can anyone see the solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you look at the error? Is your JAVA environment configured properly?

Comment: @peter: I didn't know that at the time. As I've said I was beginner at all posible fields. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you did not define Java. Please add JAVA_HOME to .bashrc

Comment: That seems to be the problem. Although, I add JAVA_HOME to '/etc/profile'. Which approach to the problem is better in your opinion?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: What kind of shell do you use? Each shell has configuration file. Add JAVA_HOME to .bashrc if you use bash for your user and to .zsh, for example, if you use zsh. I prefer to add JAVA_HOME to .bashrc configuration file. But your decision is not bad too :)

Comment: I use bash. Can you tell me your point of view - why do you prefer it? I love my solution only coz it's working :-)

Comment: I use bash too but I have several workstation (home, office, etc.). So I can just put same .bashrc on each workstation.